# Apex Your session has expired for google crawler

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an apex application.

When browsing all the pages by a human user either myself or another user, everything works fine. When I check the table : **apex_workspace_activity_log** I don't see any errors.

My application has the 0 session mechanism. It's handled through my apache configuration :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$              
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./apex/f?p=MyApplication:$1:0 [L]             
RewriteRule ^$ ./apex/f?p=MyApplication:Home:0 [L]
```

This apache config works really fine for me.

The app has also Rejoin Sessions to true.

However when my website is crawled by Google I see too many errors: **Your session has expired** in the table **apex_workspace_activity_log**

The errors occus in a certain Ajax plugin while I don't have any ajax Callback in my page...

The error occurs in all my public pages and there are always two errors at the same time (same session id, same page,...)

Here is a screenshot of the error :

[image]

Has anyone an idea about the source of the problem please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this post from the ApexNinjas?
http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/2011/04/making-your-apex-website-google-friendly/

Notably:

> 3. Create a sitemap and submit it to Google Creating a sitemap is proably the most important SEO tool you might use for your APEX
>      website. One of the reasons APEX websites are are so poorly indexed by
>      Google is because of the Session ID present in the URL:
>
> http://localhost:8081/apex/f?p=200:201:1299967722844160::NO:201:P201_ARTICLE_ID:1940.
>
> Every time Google crawls your website it finds the the same page with
>   a different URL, because the session id is always different. So Google
>   might index the same page thousands of times because of this. And, as
>   page with old session ids tend to “disappear”, Google record that
>   pages from your site are no longer available, will create statistics
>   with all the crawl errors and give your website poor ranking.
>
> So you must create a sitemap where every URL from your site is
>   stripped from the Session_ID.

Here's a more recent post that explains the same:
https://insum.ca/search-engine-optimization-with-apex-creating-a-google-sitemap/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually this is exactly why I'm rewriting my URLs... it's because Google struggles with indexing them. Through the apache configuration my URL's look like www.example.com/pagename and no more like www.example.com/apex/f?p=appname:pagename:session So the 0 session mechanisme the guys are talking about in the articles is already in place and should be transparent to google. Do you have any other idea please ? Thanks

Comment: I also confirm that the site map is already there with the friendly URL's : www.example.com/page1 www.example.com/page2...

Comment: You're not providing enough detail to help. Do you force traffic to the www subdomain? How did you create your sitemap? Can you show it to us? Did you submit your site map to Google using their Webmaster tool?